# Flex 4 - How to override paste event in DataGrid ItemRenderer

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex4, paste

I am trying to figure out how to override the default paste logic in a Flex 4 DataGrid ItemRenderer. Does anyone know how to do this?

I am trying to capture the event when a user hits Ctrl-V while a cell in the DataGrid has focus and override the logic there.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's your answers:

http://mannu.livejournal.com/348299.html

And here's an implementation:

http://hillelcoren.com/2009/09/17/import-export-copy-paste-flex-datagrid/